# Why is the transition property not working for box-shadow?

Tags: css, button, hover, css-transitions

I want to create a smooth hover button effect by transitioning a `box-shadow`. Why does the hover transition not work? What errors might be causing it to not function as expected?

```css
body{
  background: rgb(180, 181, 180);
 }
.btn{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: rgb(172, 171, 171);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgb(84, 84, 84),-3px -3px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(215, 215, 215),rgb(84, 84, 84));
}

.btn:hover{
  transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px rgb(84, 84, 84),inset -3px -3px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have transition between `inset` and non inset shadows. Make sure you always have both of them and play with color opacity:

```css
 body{
  background: rgb(180, 181, 180); 
}
.btn{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: rgb(172, 171, 171);
  box-shadow: 
    inset 3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84 / 0%),
    inset -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255 / 0%),
     3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84),
    -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255);
  transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(215, 215, 215),rgb(84, 84, 84));
}

.btn:hover{
  box-shadow: 
    inset 3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84),
    inset -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255),
     3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84 / 0%),
    -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255 / 0%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="btn"></div>
```

You can also play with the position as well:

```css
body{
 background: rgb(180, 181, 180); 
}
.btn{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: rgb(172, 171, 171);
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 rgb(84 84 84 / 0%),
    inset 0 0 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 0%),
     3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84),
    -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255);
  transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(215, 215, 215),rgb(84, 84, 84));
}

.btn:hover{
  box-shadow: 
    inset 3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84),
    inset -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255),
     0 0 0 rgb(84 84 84 / 0%),
     0 0 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a `transition` for a `inset box-shadow` on an element the non `:hovered` state **must** also be an `inset box-shadow`.

You can work around this by creating a new parent element and setting an `inset` `box-shadow` and a `transition` on the new element.

```css
.btn {
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84 / 0%), inset -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255 / 0%), 3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84), -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255);
}

.btn-container:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px rgb(84, 84, 84), inset -3px -3px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn-container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(215, 215, 215), rgb(84, 84, 84));
  transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84 / 0%), inset -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255 / 0%), 3px 3px 5px rgb(84 84 84), -3px -3px 5px rgb(255 255 255);
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background: rgb(172, 171, 171);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```